# Unable to get Window Handle of a process

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, process, automation

**What I am trying to do**

I am looping through executable paths, starting a process for each executable and then attempting to retrieve the window handle of each process. I then use this window handle to resize or move the process on the screen.

**The Problem**

Most of the time this works no problem, however I have noticed that if I execute an image file (.jpg for example) that the code fails to get the window handle and throws a InvalidOperationException, there fore meaning I am unable to resize/move the window.

**Why I Think It Happens**

A little bit of reading shows me that this process is using the dllhost.exe process. From what I've read thus far, it seems to me that permissions are restricted to this process, therefore the necessary properties to do the work I need to do are not available.

**Is There a Workaround/Solution**

Does anyone have any ideas of a workaround for this? I'm thinking I may have to create a custom solution where we detect whether or not we really can get the window handle, if not I can prompt the user to let them know. In this particular case, I could offer them to open the executable in a different program that doesn't use dllhost.exe

**A Screenshot Of Exceptions**

[image: Exceptions]

**The Code**

```
private Boolean executeProgram(string executionPath,
                                       int height,
                                       int width,
                                       int heightOffset,
                                       int widthOffset)
        {
            Boolean rtn = false;

            Process prs = new Process();

            IntPtr mWH = IntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                //TODO Need to create another process if process already exists, i.e if you start a media file default player
                //opens it, we need to ensure that another player is instantiated to play the new file
                prs.StartInfo.FileName = executionPath;

                prs.Start();

                //Move to this applications window after starting to allow the target window for manipulation.
                SwitchToThisWindow(thisApp, false);

                //Loop until a window handle has successfully be assigned, process executes too fast otherwise
                //and we will fail getting the window handle without this while loop.                   
                while(mWH == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    mWH = prs.MainWindowHandle;
                }

                if(MoveWindow(mWH, widthOffset, heightOffset, width, height, true))
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Moved!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Not Moved!");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = "Error Encountered!" + Environment.NewLine;
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(msg + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                prs.Dispose();
            }             

            return rtn;
        }
```

**Exception Message**

No process is associated with this object

---

Event the smallest amount of guidance is appreciated. Thank you.